# How to load view file content in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am working in Codeigniter 4 and trying to call $this->renderSection from view. This is my dir structure.

controller

```
--AZ

  -- Dashboard.php
```

views

```
--AZ

  -- layout
    --- template.php  

  --include
    --- dashboard-layout.php
```

dashboard.php

first i am trying to call AZ directory view.This is my controller file Dashboard.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\AZ;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;


class Dashboard extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {       
        $session = session();
        if (!$session->get('admin_id'))
        {
           redirect('login');
        }
    } 
    public function index()
    {
        
        $data['maincontent']='AZ/dashboard';
        return view('AZ/layout/template',$data);
    }
}
```

This is my template.php file in layout directory.

```
<?= $this->extend('AZ/template/dashboard-layout') ?>

<?= $this->section($maincontent) ?>
    
<?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

It's showing header but not showing content from dashboard.php file in view.

dashboard.php in view/AZ dirctory.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-header">
    <div id="breadcrumb"> <a href="index.html" title="Go to Home" class="tip-bottom"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a></div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

In dashboard-layout.php there is my header then i am trying to call view by using

$this->renderSection($maincontent);

and then footer. I am using dashboard-laayout.php in layout.php file. I have added code above of this file.

Comment: there is no `AZ/dashboard` in your view

Comment: you didn't mentioned `'AZ/template/dashboard-layout'` path as well

Comment: i have mentioned dashboard.php in AZ and it's code as well

Comment: i have mentioned dashboard-layout in layout.php file